# Magento 2 : Join 2 tables in Existing collection

Tags: magento2, collection, join-table

I've been trying to join 2 tables with the existing collection of Customers (**`customer_entity`**).

I've added like below.

```
$items->getSelect()->join('customer_entity_text as second', 'main_table.entity_id = second.entity_id');
```

Above is working fine, But if i add one more table to join with this is that is `customer_entity_varchar` than its not working.

Below is my code to join 2 tables.

```
$items->getSelect()->join('customer_entity_text as second', 
'main_table.entity_id = second.entity_id')
->join('customer_entity_varchar as third', 'main_table.entity_id = third.entity_id');
```

Any guide ?

*

Comment: It should work fine for more than 2 tables also. Can you share your code for 3 tables?

Comment: just a question: why do you want to join and not simple addAttributeToSelect()?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Check i've updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do with the addition of joins , example :
(substitute your columns)

```
$items->getSelect()->join(
       ['table1join'=>$collection->getTable('customer_entity_text')],
                    'e.entity_id = table1join.product_id',
                    ['column1'=>'table1join.column1','column2'=>'table1join.column2']);
$items->getSelect()->join(
                    ['table1join'=>$collection->getTable('main_table')],
                    'e.entity_id = table1join.product_id',
                    ['table2column1'=>'table1join.column1','table2column1'=>'table1join.column2']);
$items->getSelect()->join(
                ['table2join'=>$collection->getTable('customer_entity_varchar')],
                'e.entity_id = table2join.product_id',
                ['table3column1'=>'table2join.column1','table3column1'=>'table2join.column2']);
```

I hope my answer brings you closer to the solution.